# Finding bounding box with long/lat and long/lat delta

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am hoping to get a better understanding of coordinates with this question.  I have:
Latitude: +40.71142919
Longitude: -74.00916065
LongitudeDelta: 0.600
LatitudeDelta:  0.600

How can I find out how big is the bounding box based on these information I have.  Does anyone know if there exist a website where I can punch in these numbers and find out?

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. Search for "Distance Calculator, geographic" or similar. Something like [this](http://boulter.com/gps/distance/) should help. Only from the numbers you can see that the area is around 0.6 nautical miles wide, which is around 1100m.